# SUM the column in parts and it calculates different to the entire column SUM

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-formula

If I sum a large column separately in individual sections, and sum those results, it adds up to be slightly different than if I sum the entire column at once.

The value is off by ~ 0.00000000001 - but my conditional formatting picks this up and it is different - despite the fact they are summing the same values.

The formatting of all cells are set to 'Number'.

I can't figure out why or how this would happen - does anyone have some idea? Has something like this happened to you before when working with accurate values?

Comment: its almost certainly caused by the inherent accuracy problems of binary floating point

Comment: Thanks for the comment Charles - if this is the case - do you know of a solution to this problem, or will I be forced to round the values in my conditional formating (to only check to ~10 decimal points)?

Comment: If you are comparing numbers then use a tolerance: if(abs(a1-a2)<0.000001),"Equal","NotEqual")  Adjust the tolerance to suit your situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/78113) on Microsoft's web site. It discusses limitations in Excel's arithmetic and possible ways to deal with them.

I can't imagine that your input numbers have 15 digits of precision, so probably the easiest solution is to round your multiplication/division/etc. results (which I assume you have to get you to the 15 decimal digits).